# vi tab completion works only in some directories

Tags: bash, vim, bashrc, auto-completion

I have moved from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 (new installation). On 14.04 I had no problems with tab completion. However on 16.04 I have problems especially with vi:

In some directories (e.g. ~/ , /etc, /usr/src, /usr/src/mywork) I type `vi a`, hit `tab` and I can tab through all files and directories which starts with a.

In other directories (/usr/src/mywork/work and all subdirctories) it doesn’t work: I type `vi a` (there are file which starts with a) and hit `tab` and I can tab only through all directories which starts with a; no files are displayed. I can edit the files if I type the full name of the file.

The tab completion work fine in all directories: for example with `cat`, `rm`; and `more`. Therefore I think that it is a problem of vi.
Please, has somebody an idea? Thanks in advance

What did I do until now?

reinstall: `aptitude reinstall bash-completion`

change ownership: `chown root:root *` (also in all mother directories)

restored .bashrc: `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.`

My .vimrc is:

```
syntax on
set t_Co=256
colorscheme a-Wombat
if &diff
    colorscheme apprentice
end
```

**Solution**

This worng behaviour is driven by a a file called `!` in the directory. If one removes the file named `!` everthing is working fine. 
However if one wants to fix the behaviour one has to install the latest git of [bash-completion](http://github.com/scop/bash-completion/commit).

**Bugreport**

Valentas has reportet this as a bug in Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: What does `complete -p vi` report?

Comment: Hi muru, the result is `complete -F _filedir_xspec vi`. I fixed it due to your comment in "vi and vim". I had a file named "!" which distrubed the tab completion. THANKS again!

Comment: You should add this as an answer. I filed a bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1637193